# How to make a CountDownTimer common to multiple activites?

Tags: android

I have Activities A,B,C,D... I create a countdowntimer in activity A....I want to call its methods in activities  B,C,D .... how do i that...I tried making the timer variable static but it has some problems and doesn't function properly...Also its not a good programming practice..So is there any other way to do this??

```
public class CountTime extends Activity {

    static MyCount count;
    Button clickBtn;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.customanim); // 5000 is
                                                                // the
                                                                // starting
                                                                // number
                                                                // (in
                                                                // milliseconds)
        // 1000 is the number to count down each time (in milliseconds)
        count = new MyCount(5000, 1000);
        count.start();
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(com.example.sample.R.id.textView1);

        clickBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        clickBtn.setText("Click me");
        clickBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent my = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
            //my.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(my);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUserInteraction();
        //count.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        count.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        count.start();
    }

    // countdowntimer is an abstract class, so extend it and fill in methods
    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("done!");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finsihed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are not creating MyCount as separate class?

Comment: write the code for timer in an activity that extends service.. start the service in activity A..

Comment: I cant create it as a new class because...i want to start a new activity in the onfinish method....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably the best approach for that will be creating a Singleton class with your Timer.

If you don't know what the Singleton is you can find it in below sources:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern